# Splitting ranges into unique ranges

Tags: algorithm, range

I have a set of ranges. Each range will be of the format

```
 {startOffset: 1, endOffset: 10, id: [1]}
```

I need to split these ranges into unique ranges with ids associated with it. For example, if input is

```
[{startOffset:  1, endOffset: 10, id: [1] }, 
 {startOffset:  5, endOffset: 15, id: [2] }, 
 {startOffset: 13, endOffset: 20, id: [3] }]
```

then I expect the output as

```
[{startOffset:  1, endOffset:  4, id: [1]}, 
 {startOffset:  5, endOffset: 10, id: [1,2]}, 
 {startOffset: 11, endOffset: 12, id: [2] }, 
 {startOffset: 13, endOffset: 15, id: [2,3]},
 {startOffset: 16, endOffset: 20, id: [3]}]
```

Is there an optimized algorithm for doing this?

Comment: Sort all endpoints together, then traverse while incrementing a counter at each startOffset and decrementing at each endOffset.

Comment: This is a basic interval merge, in examples of interval merge just replace start and end with offsetStart and offsetEnd.
It has an O(n log n) complexity due to having to sort them, the merge itself has O(n) complexity.

Comment: Any limits on offsets?

Comment: The id should be an array [] not {}, this is not valid syntax.

Comment: @maraca not valid syntax in what language, and how do you know it's applicable here?

Comment: @n.m. not valid in javascript or JSON and not consistent in itself. Once he uses {} to describe an object, once [] to describe an array and once {} to describe an array.

Comment: The question doesn't mention javascriopt or json or arrays of ids, so nothing of it is relevant.

Comment: @n.m. it is, consistency is always important. It immediately becomes more readable and is easier to understand.

Comment: @n.m. Also standards like JSON are not just for fun, they are there to make life easier, because we can agree on something and don't have to guess what some symbol means in context.

Comment: I updated the question. Changed {} to []

Comment: There is no limit for the offsets. There can be ranges within ranges also.